# nexus S partition scheme, can it be changed?

Tags: samsung-nexus-s, partitions

planning on moving from the Nexus One to the S.

the only thing I don't like about the S is the 512ram and the 1GB for apps.

I tried to search forums, but found nothing relevant about this quesiton:

Is it possible to partition it something like

```
/system 6Gb
/SD 9Gb
/swap 1Gb
```

?

i'm comfortable flashing custom roms, but i never dealt with partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's been over a year, but if you still have the Nexus S, I have found a solution. Combined emulated SDcard storage like the Nexus 4. Check the guide here: 
http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-s/general/howto-combined-emulated-storage-nexus-s-t2848752

---

in case the above link disappears, the meat of the answer is to use android LVM2 (ligical volume manager). though i'm almost sure you can do it simpler by just changing regular partitions and boot scripts.

https://github.com/steven676/android-lvm-mod

the original link *just* outline all the overly complicated steps required to push a new kernel and a few system images and change partition on android. (which will never be a perfect solution because the android vendors *never* open source all the pieces to compile a perfect kernel for every device...)

Comment: thanks! i never got the nexus S because there was no good solution to this dumb design decision :) but thanks a ton for the link! i will try to revive my nexus one with that and put my newer phone for sale! that is the only thing preventing me from still using the perfectly good nexus one

Comment: I don't know enough about the first nexus to decide if it is going to work, but I hope you succeed!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Please see [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) for more information regarding this policy.

Comment: @eldarerathis tried to summarize the most important piece on the answers. thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @eldarerathis You are right, it is my first time answering a question.:)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this helps you 100% as I've never done this on the Nexus S but I did it on the HTC Desire, which the manufacturer gave a laughably small area for user installed apps.  I follows this tutorial:

http://alpharev.nl/

Basically you're using fastboot to put a new hboot down. I suggest googling for more info about these; whether there's an existing one close enough to your requirements, or if it's easy to create them yourself.

Comment: Thanks for trying answering, but: HTC and Samsung (Nexus S) are from different manufacturers. The HTC's solution doesn't apply to the Nexus S at all...

Comment: The solution does apply - he needs to find a hboot for his device. Obviously he can't use a HTC one, because he doesn't have a HTC device.  That's what the last paragraph is all about.

Comment: the answer was correct. moved the accepted answer for posterity just because the new one has a link to the proper model tutorial. thanks it did help at the time.